# Tkinter OptionList gets messed up on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, widget

I am currently working on a User Interface using TKinter on Python 2.7.12. I started out using Windows 10 where everything went fine. Now that I transfered the code to Ubuntu (which will be the target platform) I am having trouble with an OptionList Widget.

The code for the List looks the following:

```
    ...
    optionList = ['None']+self.aPandasDataFrame.index.tolist()
    omv = StringVar(master=aPopUpwindow)
    omv.set("None")
    self.om = OptionMenu(aPopUpWindow, omv, *optionList, command = update_aPopUpWindow)
    self.om.config(width=15)
    self.om.place(x=20,y=20,width=400)
    self.om.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ...
```

The list seems to be too large for Ubuntu to display. When I click on it, only the silhouette of an OptionList appears without text. By clicking into it, the program behaves as if I actually did a selection. The only way to currently solve this, is to drastically remove items from the list, which is no option for the final program.

Do you have any idea how to make this work?

Thanks for your help.
Sarem

Comment: If you have so many items that "drastically [removing] items" helps, you really should think about a different solution if you are at all concerned with usability. An option menu with more than a dozen or so items will be extremely hard for your users to use.

Comment: Also, if you're going to call `place` and immediately follow that with a call to `grid`, you can remove the call to `place`. Only one geometry manager can have control of a widget, and it's always the last one that you use.

Comment: Use a listbox (with scrolbar) as option_menu.